# If condition not working in trigger

Tags: trigger

I have written a trigger to update one custom field on activity which is a lookup to account.

I have to update that field with the account for account and one custom object (property relation)

When i just run a trigger for Account , it works .But when i have written the whole trigger, Its not updating the activity field for account .The trigger is working fine for Property relation object.

This is my trigger

```
trigger populateAccount on Task (before insert,before update) {
    List<Id> AccountIds = new List<Id>();
    String strTempId;
    if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate){
        for(Task t : trigger.new){
            strTempId = string.valueOf(t.WhatId);
            System.debug('++++++++Test strTempId+++++++++++:'+strTempId.startsWith('001'));
            if(strTempId != null && strTempId.startsWith('001')){
                System.debug('++++++++InIF+++++++++++');
                t.Account__C = t.WhatId;
            }
            else if(strTempId.startsWith('a0p')){
                AccountIds.add(t.WhatId);
            }
        }
        map<id,id> mapAccounts  = new map<Id,id>();
        if(AccountIds.size() > 0 && AccountIds!= null){
            for(Property_Relation__c objPropertyRelation:[select id,Account__c from Property_Relation__c where id in:AccountIds]){
                mapAccounts.put(objPropertyRelation.id,objPropertyRelation.Account__c);
            }
        }

        for(Task t : trigger.new){
            t.Account__c = mapAccounts.get(t.whatId);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trigger won't update `Account__c` when you create the Task under an Account. Its because `Account__c` field is overridden to blank in this line

```
for(Task t : trigger.new){
    t.Account__c = mapAccounts.get(t.whatId);
}
```

**Reason:**

When you do a get from the map `mapAccounts` using `t.whatId` which is an Account Id it returns `null` and assigns it to `Account__c` because your map is populated with key as id of Property relation object and value as id of Account. So when you do a get from the map with id of Account it will always return null. So change that to

```
for(Task t : trigger.new){
    if(t.Account__c == NULL){
        t.Account__c = mapAccounts.get(t.whatId);
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

The added if condition checks whether the Account__c field is null and assign the value returned from mapAccounts.

For task created on Property relation object, the Account__c will be
    null it will be populated here.
For task created on Account, the Account__c is already populated in this line.

```
if(strTempId != null && strTempId.startsWith('001')){
    System.debug('++++++++InIF+++++++++++');
    t.Account__C = t.WhatId;
}
```

So it won't be null and the if condition gets skipped keeping the value.

Hope it helps.